# Problem with .htaccess redirect error

Tags: .htaccess

I'm creating a custom .htaccess redirect file and I'm running in to a strange problem

Here is my .htaccess file rules

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^postreview/ /viewreview.php [NC,PT]    
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]*)/?([^/\.]*)/?([^/\.]*)/?$ /template2.php?slash1=$1&slash2=$2&slash3=$3 [L]
```

To sum up what I am trying to achieve:
1. Force www 
2. Have the 3 slash areas translated to variables for tempalte2.php
3. send postreview to viewreview.php

Most of what I am trying to do is working, but I have a strange bug.

When I enter "site.com/slash1" It redirect to "www.site.com/site.com/slash1/"
But if I enter "site.com/slash1" it redirects to www.site.com/slash1/

For some reason it also adds a "/" to the end of everything. Not sure why..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason it also adds a "/" to the end of everything. Not sure why..

It's due to this rule

```
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Change it to

```
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: When I change it to `RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]` I get a: Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Comment: @Jason Small: Change it from `[R=301,L]` to just `[L]`, or remove it completely, since you're already doing the same redirect in the second line of your `.htaccess`

Comment: Awesome That fixed the adding of the slash.  Any idea on how to stop this from happening: When I enter "site.com/slash1" It redirect to "www.site.com/site.com/slash1/ Note: I want to keep the forcing of www